# ESP32 HTTP Request handles Go webserver response, but fails on node JS servers

Tags: esp32, http

I've set up an esp32 board (wemos d1 r32) to send a request to a server hosted on my local network. If I set up a very basic go server, the board handles the response fine (200 with the appropriate body content). Once I switch to a Node JS Server, it only responds with a `400` status code. Weirdest of all none of the `console.log` calls in the route handlers get called, which indicates that it quits before it even gets to the express server. I've tested that the server returns the body & status code I want using postman, all looks good.

I've tried different frameworks (Koa) to see if this is related to Express, but it doesn't work with that either. I assume its something to do with NodeJS?

**Express server**

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  req.statusCode = 200;
  res.send("200");
});

app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.setTimeout(50000);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.setHeader("Location", "123");
  res.setHeader("Server", "123");
  req.statusCode = 200;
  res.send("200");
});

app.listen(8090, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${8090}`);
});
```

**Go server**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    for name, headers := range w.Header() {
        for _, h := range headers {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v: %v\n", name, h)
        }
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello\n")
}

func headers(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    for name, headers := range req.Header {
        for _, h := range headers {
            fmt.Fprintf(w, "%v: %v\n", name, h)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("?")

    http.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)
    http.HandleFunc("/headers", headers)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
```

**Arduino script**

```
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>

// #define LOG_LOCAL_LEVEL ESP_LOG_VERBOSE
#include "esp_log.h"

const char* ssid = "xxx";
const char* password = "xxx";

String webserver = "http://192.168.0.19:8090/hello";

String qrCode;

void WiFiStationConnected(WiFiEvent_t event, WiFiEventInfo_t info){
  Serial.println("Connected to AP successfully!");
}

void WiFiGotIP(WiFiEvent_t event, WiFiEventInfo_t info){
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void WiFiStationDisconnected(WiFiEvent_t event, WiFiEventInfo_t info){
  
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Disconnected from WiFi access point");
  Serial.print("WiFi lost connection. Reason: ");
  Serial.println(info.disconnected.reason);
  Serial.println("Trying to Reconnect");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  delay(5000);
}

void setup() {
  esp_log_level_set("*", ESP_LOG_VERBOSE);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial2.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello, ESP32!");
  Serial.println(WiFi.getMode());
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());

  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiStationConnected, WiFiEvent_t::SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_CONNECTED);
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiGotIP, WiFiEvent_t::SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP);
  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiStationDisconnected, WiFiEvent_t::SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
}

int cnt = 0;

void loop() {
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    int  ch = Serial2.read();
    char character = ch;
    Serial.print(ch);

    // end char
    if(character == 13){
      Serial.print("\n");
      Serial.println(qrCode);
      Serial.println(cnt);
      qrCode = "";
      cnt = 0;
      send(qrCode);
    } else {
      cnt = ch + cnt;
      qrCode = qrCode + character;
    }
  }
}

void tryWifi() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  int status = WiFi.status();
  while (status == 6 || status == 4 || status == 5 || status == 1) {
    Serial.print("Failed to connect:"); 
    Serial.print(status);
    Serial.print("\n");
    delay(1500);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  }
}

void send(String json) {
  HTTPClient http; 

  if(http.begin(webserver)){    

      int httpCode = http.GET();
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      http.addHeader("Host", "something");
      // client.print("Content-Length: ");
      delay(1500);  
      
      Serial.println(httpCode);
      Serial.println(http.getString());
      if (httpCode > 0) {
      Serial.printf("[HTTP] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
        if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
          String payload = http.getString();                 
          if (payload != "false"){
            Serial.println(payload); 
            delay(1500);  
          } else {
          Serial.println("Bad Playload");
          }
        } else {
          
        }
      } else {
      Serial.println("Error sending to HTTP");
      }
      http.end(); 
    } else {
      Serial.println("?");
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Arduino code reads like this:

```
  int httpCode = http.GET();
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  http.addHeader("Host", "something");
  // client.print("Content-Length: ");
  delay(1500);  
  
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.println(http.getString());
  if (httpCode > 0) {
```

The call `http.GET()` actually performs the HTTP request. You're adding headers *after* you perform the request. They need to be added before it. So your code should read:

```
  // http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  int httpCode = http.GET();

  // delay(1500);   -- there's no need to call delay() here
  
  Serial.println(httpCode);
  Serial.println(http.getString());
  if (httpCode > 0) {
```

HTTP status code 400 means "bad request". Some web servers will return this code if headers that they expect to see are missing or have non-sensical values. The Go and Javascript web servers are different implementations and may behave differently with malformed requests.

I've removed "Host" header as [`HTTPClient` does this for you](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.cpp#L1186). And there's no need for the `delay()` call after calling `http.GET()`.

**Edit**: I also commented out the "Content-Type" header as it makes no sense on a GET request, thanks to @EdgarBonet for mentioning that. I'm leaving it there as a comment to make it clear that that any headers should be added *before* the request is performed.

Comment: Note also that `"Content-Type"` does not make sense on an HTTP request. The OP probably means `"Accept"`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet  Thanks, good point. It does actually make sense on a PUT or POST request that has a body, but not on a GET, which should never have a body. I've edited the answer. I suspect OP was just throwing in random lines of code to see if they fixed their problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I had the `Content-Type` header there as I intend to use a POST request w/ a json body. I've moved the call to set the header before the request is fired, nice catch!

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out after an unreasonable amount of time that the request fails with a 400 as it doesn't have a slash at the end of the URL (`http://192.168.1.208:8090` -> `http://192.168.1.208:8090/`). This must be something specific to NodeJS, as it works ok on a go server.